# Missing dependency Information

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.bea.core:weblogic-stax:jar:1.10 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.bea.core:utils-full:jar:1.10 is missing, no dependency information available
```

I cannot find these JARs on the web and I need them for my project, any clue how I can find them?

Answer (score 0):

I think they are not part of Maven Central, you may need to install them manually

Try to search files on path
oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/

Manually install jar like

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.bea.core -DartifactId=weblogic-stax -Dversion=<your_version> -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:\webservers\bea\modules\your_jar_name.jar
```

Comment: How exactly do I search in that Directory? Sorry for being noobish

Comment: you need to download weblogic server (weblogic 12.1.2 )